# get element value using jquery

Tags: jquery, get, element

How do I get the value of the cell with class EventAddress using jquery?

```
<table cellpadding="10" class ="EventDetail">
    <tr>
        <td class="TableFields">Who Should Enroll?:</td>
        <td>Everyone 18 and older who would like to attend</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="TableFields">Location:</td>
        <td class="EventAddress">1300 Albany Street,Beech Grove ,IN</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you with "value" mean the content of the td-element, then you could do:

```
$(".EventAddress").text();
```

Comment: You know... You can tip up the answer that you like for approve it as the valid one...

Comment: @AJSwift Nope. Val only works on textarea, input and select elements. For getting text is valid .text(); and .html();

Comment: @AJSwift No, `.val()` would not work, since it return the content of the value-attribute of an input element. Here's the documentation about .val(): http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 1):

```
alert($('.EventAddress').html());
```

Basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/LMBsc/