# jquery get element by attribute and class

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have an element:

```
<div>
     <div class="foo bar" data-id="12345"></div>
     <div class="foo bar" data-id="678"></div>
     <div class="foo bar" data-id="910"></div>
</div>
```

How can I get the element with `data-id="12345"` and  `class="foo bar"` ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944302/jquery-select-an-elements-class-and-id-at-the-same-time

Comment: possible duplicate of [get element value using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555064/get-element-value-using-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('[data-id=12345].foo.bar').css('color', 'peru');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LBqhP/1/

Comment: I love that there's a colour called 'peru'

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$("div.foo.bar[data-id='12345']");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access your div that has `class='foo bar'` and `data-id=12345` :

```
var element = $("div.foo.bar[data-id=12345]");
```

If you want simply to access the first div element that has class='foo bar' :

```
var element =  $("div.foo.bar:nth-child(1)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Chain the class selectors, then filter based on the data parameter:

```
$(function() {
    $("div.foo.bar").filter(function() {
        return $(this).data("id") == "12345";
    });
});
```

[***jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/2gbJb/) 
You can also easily wrap this logic into a reusable and extensible function:

```
function getDivWithDataId(id) {
    return $("div.foo.bar").filter(function() {
        return $(this).data("id") == id;
    });
}
```

which returns the jQuery collection matching the relevant div elements.

You can extend this to include classes (by passing an array of classes, like `['foo','bar']`):

```
function getDivWithDataId(id, classes) {
    return $("div").filter(function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        var classMatch = true;

        $.each(classes, function(idx, val) {
            if (!$self.is(val)) classMatch = false;
        }

        return $(this).data("id") == id && classMatch;
    });
}
```