# Get a contents of a label using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get the contents of a `label` using jQuery. So for example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
<label for="checkbox1">Get the text of this label</label>
```

Thanks

Comment: This really is jQuery 101 - the kind of thing you should be able to research yourself. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get element value using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555064/get-element-value-using-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Rory McCrossan already points out, this is really basic jQuery. Please note the link he provides: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

```
$('[for=checkbox1]').text();
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work -

```
<label for="checkbox1" id="xyz">Get the text of this label</label>
var t = $('#xyz').html();
```

Comment: No need for an extra attribute, you can use an [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/).

Comment: Wasn't aware of it. I'm not at all good when it comes to javascript

Answer (score 2):

```js
var value=($('label').html());
alert(value);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
<label for="checkbox1">Get the text of this label</label>
```

Comment: You might want to mention that is will only work when there is just one `label` on the page (ie the first). https://jsfiddle.net/7ezb9zxa/

Comment: Yes, when you bind an event on *all* labels, that definitely works. However that is not what the the TS asks. And also it doesn't work in your answer code, my fiddle shows that. It's not that your code is wrong, but I do believe it's important that you point out in your code that this only works for the first label on the page, or when binding an event to it. Be as clear as you can in your answering.

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert($('label[for="checkbox1"]').text())
    });




</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
<label for="checkbox1">Get the text of this label</label>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: actually the best as it uses both the `label` tag and the `for` attribute